# Php code help regarding images

Tags: php, image, image-processing

So I have this php script which **generates random text on an image.**
The text file is a different php file and the image file is a seperate php file.
The `image.php` file calls this `text.php` to select a random text.

This version works fine, but is it possible to generate a random image on my existing image file?

I have included the current versions of my code.

This is text.php:

```
<?php
    $t[] = 'Sample text 1 ';
    $t[] = 'Sample text 2';
    shuffle($t);
?>
```

This is image.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'text.php';
    $text = wordwrap($t[0], 31, "\n", true); //text
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty.jpg'); //background image
?>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Captcha? Also, what do you mean with "random image"?

Comment: No not a captcha.
Want to diplay randomly genrated image over a fixed image background :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit unclear.. You don't want text.php then you can directly use it's code in image.php as shown below.

image.php

```
<?php
$t[] = 'Sample text 1 ';
$t[] = 'Sample text 2';
shuffle($t);
$text = wordwrap($t[0], 31, "\n", true); //text
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty.jpg'); //background image
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion,but,is it possible to generate a random image over a fixed image?
That is what I wanted to ask :)

Comment: So you want random numbers or random text on image??

Comment: @VibhaJ-I want some other random image over a fixed image.Is that possible?

Comment: What is defination of random image?? Give example. You want image rotator??

Comment: By Random Image I mean, I have set of images, about a 50 of them and whenever a user visits my page he should see a random image out of those 50 :)

Comment: @VibhaJ-And of course,these images will be displayed on a image background.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create an image with random text this will do it

image.php

```
require_once 'text.php';
header("Content-type: image/png");

$string = wordwrap($t[0], 31, "\n", true); //text
$font  = 2;
$width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
$height = imagefontheight($font);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor ($width,$height);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$white); 
imagestring ($image,$font,0,0,$string,$black);
imagepng ($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

**UPDATED CODE TO YOUR RESPONSE:**
if you want to get your random text over a specific image

```
require_once 'text.php';
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = wordwrap($t[0], 31, "\n", true); //text


$image  = ImageCreateFromJPEG("img_empty.jpg");

//Defining color. Making the color of text as red (#FFF) as 255,000,000
$color = imagecolorallocate($image , 255, 000, 000); // 

//put string over image with $color as color
imagestring($image,5,126,22,$string,$color);

imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);
```

The above code will put a red color random text over your specified image.this works for me. Also try changing the colors defined in imagecolorallocate() function.

reference: http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion,but,is it possible to generate a random image over a fixed image?
That is what I wanted to ask :)

Comment: This is more related to colour changing of text.
I want a random image over a fixed image.Is that possible? :)

Comment: @AviralKacholia: this doesnt make sense. please clarify by editing your qn and provide requiremnts clearly.

Comment: Hmm..fine,I have an image background.
I want some random images pulled from my database to be displayed ON that background image.That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Several options here

1. Have several background-images saved and select one randomly among them.
2. Use [GD and Image Functions](http://no.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) to draw on your existing image before outputting it (look at [imageline()](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php) for drawing lines for example).
3. Use GD's [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) to create the image, to even get random width/height.

Comment: Hmm..so by using GD and Image functions,I can display a random image over a fixed background?
Thanks.

Comment: @AviralKacholia Like I wrote in my answer, with GD and Image Functions you can draw random stuff onto your existing image, and either output that directly to the user or save it to a location of your choice.